# Logging in and scraping a site like ft.com with BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this url: https://www.ft.com/content/87d644fc-73a4-11e7-aca6-c6bd07df1a3c

It corresponds to an article that requires signing up. I signed up and can see the content in my browser. However when I use this code with the url above:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'lxml')
with open('ctp_output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
        f.write(tag.text.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

Especially, it redirects me on the signup page. Is there any way to be logged in to have access to the article when scraping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the basics.

Go to the login page. If you use the Chrome browser you can position your mouse over the email input area and use the context menu (in Windows) and then its 'Inspect' entry to reveal the `form` element that will be used to submit your email address. It looks like this.

```
<form name="enter-email-form" action="/login/submitEmail" class="js-email-lookup-form" method="POST" data-test-id="enter-email-form" novalidate="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="location" value="https://www.ft.com/content/87d644fc-73a4-11e7-aca6-c6bd07df1a3c">
        <input type="hidden" name="continueUrl" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="readerId" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="loginUrl" value="/login?location=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ft.com%2Fcontent%2F87d644fc-73a4-11e7-aca6-c6bd07df1a3c">
        <div class="lgn-box__title">
            <h1 class="lgn-heading--alpha">Sign in</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="o-forms-group">
            <label for="email" class="o-forms-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="o-forms-text js-email" name="email" maxlength="64" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" required="">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" style="display:none">
            <label for="password">
        </label></div>
        <div class="o-forms-group">
            <button class="o-buttons o-buttons--standout o-buttons--big" type="submit" name="Next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

You will need to gather the `action` attribute from the `form` element and **all** the name-value pairs from the `input` statements. You use these in a POST request with the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

You do this once for your email address and once for your password. Then you should be able to issue the GET for the URL with requests.

I must warn you that I haven't actually tried this with that particular site.

Comment: If you do that then we could change the title of your question to, say, logging into ft.com so that others might benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup, I'd recommend the [MechanicalSoup](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. It is a very lightweight layer on top of BeautifulSoup (to parse HTML) and requests (to fetch pages), but it will deal for you with things like filling-in a form properly (i.e. what you need here), following relative links, ...

MechanicalSoup is also limited in the sense that it doesn't interpret JavaScript code, hence won't work on a website relying on JavaScript, but it reduces the manual effort compared to using BeautifulSoup and urllib or requests directly.

(Note: I'm one of the authors of MechanicalSoup)